# Does the rational function $\frac{x}{x-1}$ meet the criterion: $f:[0,3] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and so is surjective on that interval?

Tags: calculus

Does a function on a closed interval from $[a,c]$ (domain) have to be defined at every point of $a$ to $c$ or can they be undefined on a value in between (let's say $b$)?

Comment: The function is not defined for $x=1$. More generally, a function defined on a domain would be have to be defined everywhere in this interval

Answer (score 1):

If the interval $[a,c]$ is the *domain* of a function, then by definition the function must be defined at *all* points of the interval.